# Javascript "match" error in angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am getting typeerror:cannot read property of 'match' undefined

```
var numInput = document.getElementById('input');

// Listen for input event on numInput.
numInput.addEventListener('input', function(){
    // Let's match only digits.
    var num = this.value.match(/^\d+$/);
    if (num === null) {
        // If we have no match, value will be empty.
        this.value = "";
    }
}, false)
```

Comment: @yurzui — Nooo! That will **definitely** break it!

Comment: [I can't reproduce the problem](http://jsbin.com/boxukohabu/1/edit?html,js,output). It works fine when I test it. You need to provide a real [mcve]. Yours is not *complete*.

Comment: Are you sure that angular is the right tag for this question?

Comment: @Quentin I did not notice property name :) I thought he uses some component property not `input.value`

Comment: no,I am getting error . when i am executing in angular 2

Comment: while using ionic framework getting error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this.value is undefined because you are not using an arrow function ( => ). Try this

```
numInput.addEventListener('input', () => {
// Let's match only digits.
var num = this.value.match(/^\d+$/);
if (num === null) {
    // If we have no match, value will be empty.
    this.value = "";
}
}, false)
```

Comment: There is no sign of `this.value` being defined for whatever `this` is in the outer scope. On the other hand, the `this` value for an event listener will be the element the event fired on, which is an input element, which will have a `value` property, which works: http://jsbin.com/boxukohabu/1/edit?html,js,output